# Puppet : Use external facts inside templates

Tags: erb, puppet, puppetlabs-apache, facter

I have defined some key value pairs in `/etc/facter/facts.d/value.txt` file.

I could use those keys inside my init.pp script and successfully for the values using:

```
${key1}
```

I want to get those values inside my template file. I have used:

```
<%= @key1 %>
```

but it doesn't give me the value.

What is the correct way to get the value of the external fact inside the template?

Comment: What you tried Should Work. Is `key1` the actual name? If not, can you provide it? There may be a variable name issue.

Comment: This is my values.txt file which is inside the facts.d folder

key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3

Still I couln't solve this issue

Comment: I could solve the issue. Actuaaly I used "portOffset" as my key name. I changed it to "portoffset" (without any capital letter) and it works fine. Is this a issue with external facters ?

Comment: That is **precisely** why I asked for the actual fact name. I'm not aware that fact names are forced to lower case, but seeing as all core facts use lower case only, that may indeed be a limitation.